# Windows batch script and plink.exe

Tags: batch-file, plink

I would like to combine Windows batch script and plink.exe tool (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and run as loop but no luck, below is mine.
thanks for your help

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (D:\script\ip.txt) do (
pushd C:\Windows\System32\tools
plink.exe -l root -pw xxxx root@%%i lsb_release -sr | grep 12.04
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
msg * Sorry, this is NOT a Precise version
exit
) else
(
pushd C:\Windows\System32\tools
msg * Cheers, welcome to Precise!
)
)
```

or it simply to run a Windows batch script as loop.

```
if it is Ubuntu 10.04
do nothing
else if (meant, it's Ubuntu 12.04)
already LibreOffice installed
do nothing
else
install LibreOffice
exit
```

and repeat to next ip address in the ip.txt file

Comment: what is the error you got ? is it working for only one ip ?

Comment: hi, I got nothing, seems it did not work properly.

Comment: it was only worked if

    @echo off
    for /f %%i in (D:\script\ip.txt) do (
    pushd C:\Windows\System32\tools
    plink.exe -l root -pw xxxx root@%%i "lsb_release -sr | grep 12.04"> D:\debug.txt
    )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for-in-do was incorrect and a misplaced ( after the `else`

```
 @echo off
 for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "D:\script\ip.txt" ') do (
 pushd C:\Windows\System32\tools
 plink.exe -l root -pw xxxx root@%%i lsb_release -sr | grep 12.04
  if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    msg * Sorry, this is NOT a Precise version
      pause
      exit /b
    ) else (
      msg * Cheers, welcome to Precise!
  )
 popd
 )
```

This is in answer to the followup details - it may need some work as I don't know how plink works or the way it handles Linux commands.

```
 @echo off
 for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "D:\script\ip.txt" ') do (
 pushd C:\Windows\System32\tools
 plink.exe -l root -pw xxxx root@%%i lsb_release -sr | grep 12.04
  REM if 12.04 not found then print message and abort
  if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 is required.
      pause
      exit /b
  )

plink.exe -l root -pw xxxx root@%%i (dpkg -l | grep libreoffice-core
   REM if libre is found and errorlevel is zero then abort silently
   if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
      exit /b
  ) else (
   REM if it reaches here then it will install LibreOffice
   plink.exe -l root -pw xxxx root@%%i sudo apt-get install libreoffice
 )
 popd
)
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked fine, tks so much.
Besides, your suggestion just solve 2 conditions, it would be much appreciate if help me to solve with more conditions.
It looks like:
    if Ubuntu 10.04
    do nothing
    else if LibreOffice already installed
    do nothing
    else
    install LibreOffice
    repeat

Comment: I need you to tell me A) how to determine if LibreOffice is installed B) what command is used to install LibreOffice.

Comment: Hi, to check LibreOffice is already installed or not, I use (dpkg --get-selections | grep libreoffice-core | awk '{print $1}') or (dpkg -l | grep libreoffice-core  | awk '{print $2}').
To do install LibreOffice, I proceed, assuming install from repo, (sudo apt-get install libreoffice).
Tks.

Comment: I added a section to the answer above.  I hope it helps.

Comment: yep it worked a half, please refer the image http://upanh.in/bdg.png >>> explain: even I changed "libreoffice-core" to whatever, it returns as image, tks for your care again.

Comment: `| awk '{print $2}') |grep libre` Remove this section from my code and try it.